# Reversable algorithm for to/from latitude and longitude and 3D point

Tags: algorithm, geometry, latitude-longitude, coordinate-transformation

I know there are other questions similar to this one, but most of them deal with only converting one to the other. But I am searching for a algorithms that convert to and from each other. Simply using one of each has not produced the desired results.

For my purposes a unit sphere is more then acceptable. Any radius value would be 1.

Here are my current methods for performing this, in simple psudocode.

From latitude and longitude to a point on a unit sphere.

```
x = cos( longitude ) * sin( latitude )
y = sin( longitude ) * sin( latitude )
z = cos( latitude )
```

From 3D coordinates on a unit sphere to latitude and longitude.

```
latitude = acos( z )
longitude = atan2( x, y )
```

However these are not reversible and my trigonometry is not what it should be.

Comment: Many computer languages have an [atan2(y, x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function, which may be what you need.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the inherent reversibility problem.

Comment: What is the reversibility problem you are seeing? Atan2 returns an angle in the correct quadrant, whereas atan won't necessarily do that.

Comment: What do you mean that these are not reversible?  You just reversed the conversion from xyz to lat/long yourself in the question.  The only detail is the fact that `atan` won't return the angle in the correct quadrant, which is what `atan2` is for.

Comment: Edited the algorithm, but the problem remains. Try it with a latitude of 0 and a longitude of say 1 (which is about 57 degrees). The first produces 0,0,1, and feeding 0,0,1 into the second produces 0,0. Not reversible.

Comment: There's a degeneracy (multiple coordinates map to the same point in space) whenever `sin(latitude) == 0`.  For these cases the coordinate system is not invertible, but it is everywhere else.

Comment: Well the same problem occurs even if you say... use PI/2 (90°) for latitude and longitude, just not as easy of an example. In this case it outputs 0,1,0 to a point and when fed back it produces PI/2 (90°), and 0 (0°). I am not saying it is broken just because I haven't tested it enough. Honest.

Comment: `atan2` takes `y` first, not `x`.  That will fix that problem.

Comment: Okay, make an answer with that and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting from lat/long to xyz is always possible, but going from xyz to lat/long fails when `sin(lat) == 0`.  There is no solution to this in lat/long space so just stay away from it.
Other than that your formula just has a small error where `atan2` takes `y` then `x` instead of `x` then `y`.

Comment: "going from lat/long to xyz fails when sin(lat) = 0" - because it's at a pole. Also, some computer languages take the arguments in the order (x, y); e.g. Excel and OpenOffice Calc.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I figured some languages took them in the order that (I think) makes more sense, but I'm accustomed to C++, Java and Python which use `y,x`.

Comment: You can also use x,y if the 0° location is up, rather than to the right. I have done that for years due to a wonky game that does it like that.

Comment: The order (x,y) sort-of makes sense, but as it's calculating atan(y/x) I can see why the order is usually (y,x). I got the exceptions from the Wikipedia page I [linked to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) earlier.

Comment: @GuyGreer I think you mean the opposite - that Lon/Lat to XYZ is always possible, but XYZ to Lon/Lat is ambiguous.  Every Lon/Lat pair defines a unique XYZ coordinate, though multiple Lon/Lat pairs may map to the same coordinate, e.g. at a pole.  This results in ambiguity when going the other direction.